# Reading a file into character array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I have been writing code to read a file into character array using C++. I have tried to skip over white space characters but I am getting space and newline in my output array.

This is a function within the class with *label* declared as character array.

```
        //Read the label file
 80     this->label = new char[vert_count+1];
 81     std::ifstream file1;
 82     file1.open(label_file);
 83     if(file1 != NULL)
 84     {
 85         char temp; int i = 0;
 86         std::cout << "Label file opened successfully" << std::endl;
 87         if( i< vert_count)
 88         {
 89             file1.get(temp);
 90             if(temp != ' ' &&  temp != '\n'&& temp != '\t')
 91             {
 92                 label[i] = temp;
 93                 i++; 
 94             }
 95         }
 96         label[vert_count] = '\0';//putting null character to terminate
 97         file1.close(); 
 98     }
 99     else        
100         std::cout << "label file cannot be opened\n";
101     for (int i = 0; i< vert_count; i++)
102         std::cout <<label[i];
```

my input file is of format as shown below

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
1
2
H
M
O
```

The output I am getting is bunch of characters at start and then white space and new line only.

Comment: `i` is not initialized in your example.  Don't assume it will be 0.

Comment: It looks to me like you're only reading one line from the file.  There's no loop.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Even less, 1 character.

Comment: You can have a loop like int i = 0, char x; while(file1.good()) { file >> x; if(x == ' ') ;//do nothing else { label[i] = x; } }

Comment: @JimBaldwin I am beating myself right now. Thanks dude

Comment: We've all been there.  :-)  Feel free to accept the answer so I can earn me some serious respect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant (on line 87):

```
while (i < vert_count)
```